# Got stuck following a tutorial please help

Tags: mesh

I am stuck while following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28AlRLMlqW8&t=4251s&ab_channel=FlyCat

At 0:33. The youtuber highlighted the vertical line in the middle of the hexagon and did something to make it split into 2 vertical lines.

It happened pretty fast in the video so i took some screen shots too.

[image]

Can someone please tell me how he/she did it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ctrl + B (Bevel hotkey) - Move the mouse to change the size of the "gap" . Scroll the mousewheel to make extra "loops"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used the **Loop Subdivide tool**. It creates loop cut(s) around the area selected by the user.

hotkey: ctrl + r

a yellow line shows what section will be cut - click to confirm cutting this section

Once confirming the section to cut:

scroll wheel increases/decreases cuts

move mouse to slide where the cut will happen

click again to finally cut

Here's the Blender documentation for further reading: [Blender Loop Subdivide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html)

Good luck with the tutorial, hope this helps!